# Remove Object in Json File Python

Tags: python, json, telethon

I have a json file:

```
[{"uid": x, "username": "x", "firstname": "x", "lastname": "x", "access_hash": x}, {"uid": y, "username": "y", "firstname": "y", "lastname": "y", "access_hash": y}]
```

and I want to remove the the object {"uid[...]"access-hash": x} while im in a loop

and I have following code:

```
 try:
                user_to_add = InputPeerUser(user['uid'], user['access_hash'])
                add = await client(InviteToChannelRequest(target_group_entity,[user_to_add]))
                print(gr+'Added ', str(user['uid']))
                #remove the object where I used uuid acces_hash and so on
```

I hope somebody can help me, and ty in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pop()`

```
my_dict = [{"uid": 'x', "username": "x", "firstname": "x", "lastname": "x", "access_hash": 'x'}, {"uid": 'y', "username": "y", "firstname": "y", "lastname": "y", "access_hash": 'y'}]

for i in range(0,len(my_dict)-1):
    if my_dict[i]['uid'] == 'x':
        my_dict.pop(i)
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: thank you but I want to remove the whole thing like: ```{"uid": 'x', "username": "x", "firstname": "x", "lastname": "x", "access_hash": 'x'}``` <-- I want to remove this

Answer (score -1):

Please, in the future, try to read [Stack Overflow guidelines for questions posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to give a clear and complete description of your issue. Generally providing a context helps out a lot.

Regarding your issue, I'll make some assumptions. The first one is that you are iterating through the array of user objects and the second one is that every single object is unique.

You should use the `pop()` List method since you want to remove the user object you just added to the channel.

A simple example would be:

```
while(len(users_list)>0):
     users.pop(0) # You are removing the current object of the users_list.
```

Since you are removing objects from the list the length of it will logically start decreasing until it breaks the while condition.